# How to replace password for user in as400?

Tags: java, ldap, ibm-midrange

I want to replace the password in as400 by new password for a user. I am trying to do this using following code but getting error as "LDAP: error code 65 - Object Class Violation"

I don't understand I'm getting it with this code:

```
String newPassword="Passw0rd2";
String quotedPassword = "\"" + newPassword + "\"";
char unicodePwd[] = quotedPassword.toCharArray();
byte pwdArray[] = new byte[unicodePwd.length * 2];

for (int i = 0; i < unicodePwd.length; i++) {
    pwdArray[i * 2 + 1] = (byte) (unicodePwd[i] >>> 8);
    pwdArray[i * 2 + 0] = (byte) (unicodePwd[i] & 0xff);
}

String userDN="complete dn";

String newPassword="Passw0rd2";

System.out.println(charArrayToByteArray(newPassword.toCharArray()));
ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE,
                new BasicAttribute("userPassword",charArrayToByteArray(newPassword.toCharArray())));
ctx.modifyAttributes(userDN, mods);//error is comming at userDN
```

Comment: Isn't that an LDAP problem and not related to AS/400?

Comment: Does the LDAP log file show anything when the error is signaled? (Are logfiles configured?) Different causes of error code 65 can log different messages.

Answer (score 0):

Or I'm not understanding you or there is a easy way, "simply" send/quote a "remote" command as CHGUSRPRF USRPRF(username) PASSWORD(newpass), you can even create a very small CL program passing the two parameters and executing the command.